# is there way to get segment from url in angular 7 like we do in codeigniter

Tags: angular, segment

is there any way to get segment from url in angular like we can do in codeigniter

we use $this->uri->segment(1) to get first segment data (controller name) as i want to get segment in angular 7 like if i have http://localhost:4000/home/list so how can i individual get home and then list

i want to get home and list seperatly is there any best source link or any thing else that help me to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular's **Location** Service which makes it easy to interact with URL path.

You need to import it with `LocationStrategy` and `PathLocationStrategy` from `@angular/common`, add the members to your list of providers and inject Location in the constructor.

check `getPath` method which is called in `onInit`.

```
import { Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [Location, {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}]
})
export class YourClass implements OnInit {
  constructor(private location: Location) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPath();
  }

  getPath() {
    let locationPath = this.location.path();
    let locationSegments: any[];
    if (locationPath.length) locationSegments = locationPath.split('/');
    console.log(locationSegments)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ActivatedRoute.url](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#url) which is an array of [UrlSegment](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSegment)s.
`UrlSegment` has `path` and `params`, so for example you could console.log the paths like so:

1) Get a reference to `ActivatedRoute` by injecting it in your component constructor

`constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}`

2) Do stuff with the `UrlSegment` array

```
console.log(this.route.url[0].path) // log first path

this.route.url.forEach(segment => console.log(segment.path)) // log each path
```

Comment: console.log(this.route.url[0].path); it,s give me error undefine and this time my url is like this http://localhost:4200/admin/login

Answer (score 0):

import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

then inject it in contractor like route:ActivatedRoute

to get diferent segments from this url localhost:4200/admin/login

you can use this line of code route.url.value[0].path it,s will give you admin and

this line of code route.url.value[1].path it,s will give you login

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
   app: any
    
    constructor(
            private route: ActivatedRoute,
        ) {
            this.app = this.route.snapshot.url[0].path
    }
```